# Draw line before marker appear Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I am working on dynamic update using highchart.
Is there a way, wherein the line will go first on the next point before marker appear?
Currently what is happening is that, the marker appear first on the point before the line connects.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.random();
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 1000,
                    y: Math.random()
                });
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
});
```

and also if there is a way I could do to move the line movements on the center so that the right will always be blank like the image below

[image]

**Please refer to this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/687215jj/)**. 
Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spacing can be achieved with axis minPadding (space on the left) and [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.maxPadding) (space on the right).

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  tickPixelInterval: 150,
  maxPadding: 0.5
},
```

As for the animation - you can add point with a disabled marker and then set timeout which will fire after the animation is finished and it will enable marker.

```
    load: function() {

      // set up the updating of the chart each second
      var series = this.series[0];
      setInterval(function() {
        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
          y = Math.random();

        series.addPoint({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }, true, true);

        setTimeout(() => series.data[series.data.length - 1].update({marker: {enabled: true}}, true, false), 500)
      }, 1000);
    }
```

By default the animation for adding point is set to 500 so if you change the animation aduration, you need to change the delay param in setTimeout.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/687215jj/1/

Comment: thank you very much for the help. really appreciate it :)